# Remove the white top color in circular diagram or others

Tags: smartdiagram

From other questions I have worked out how to remove the hard coded shadow: `\tikzset{every shadow/.style={fill=none,shadow scale=0}}` and how to remove the hard coded border `border color=white`

What I would like to do finally is remove the gradient fill. I see options for bottom color, but when I try to add top color it breaks the build. Is there a workaround similar to the top one?

```
%TikZ & Smart Diagram requirements
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,trees,shadows,positioning,chains,matrix,calc,automata,intersections,%
                shapes.geometric,shapes.symbols,%
                shapes.arrows,backgrounds,fadings,%
                decorations.text,decorations.pathreplacing,decorations.pathmorphing,%
                arrows.meta}
\usepackage{bm,times}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\usesmartdiagramlibrary{additions}    
\begin{document}
\tikzset{every shadow/.style={fill=none,shadow scale=0}}
\smartdiagramset{
uniform color list=teal!60!teal for 5 items,
circular final arrow disabled=true,
circular distance=2.25cm,
arrow tip=to,
arrow line width=2pt,
border color=white,
additions={
additional item bottom color=teal!60!teal,
additional item border color=gray,
additional item shadow=drop shadow,
additional item offset=0.65cm,
additional arrow line width=2pt,
additional arrow tip=to,
additional arrow color=teal!60!teal,
}
}
\smartdiagramadd[circular diagram]{a,b,c,d,e}
{above of module1/Start,right of module5/End},
\smartdiagramconnect{to-}{module1/additional-module1}
\smartdiagramconnect{-to}{module5/additional-module2}
\hspace{2cm}
\smartdiagramset{module shape=diamond,
font=\scriptsize,
module minimum width=1cm,
module minimum height=1cm,
text width=1cm,
circular distance=2cm,
circular final arrow disabled=true,
}
\smartdiagram[circular diagram:clockwise]{Set up,Run,Analyse,Modify~/ Add}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you show us an example of where you try to get rid of the gradient? This is best done in an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864).

Comment: The easiest way is just to not use `fill` or `shadow` or `border color` in the first place. None of these are compulsory. So you must be using code which adds them. However, we don't know what that code is or what you might mean by 'hard coded'. Certainly they are not automatic with, say, `tikzpicture` or whatever.